# Is there a way to stop all MediaPlayers?

Tags: android, media-player

I am currently developing my first Android application by reading Dev Documentation at Android official website. What I am trying to accomplish is to play some ring sounds. A section from my code is:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class PlayRingSounds extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public void PlayRingFile(View view) {       
  switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.Button01:
      MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.aaa);
      mp1.start();
      break;
    case R.id.Button02:
      MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.bbb);
      mp2.start();
      break;        
  }
}   
}
```

The problem is when I click the 2nd button while "aaa" (sound file from 1st button) is playing, "bbb" also starts playing at the same time. Is there a way to stop "aaa" before "bbb" plays, or is there a way to stop all media players?

Update 12/30/2009 - New code is:

```
   case R.id.Button01:
       if (mp2.isPlaying())
       {
           mp2.stop();
           mp2.release();
       }
       mp1.reset();
       mp1.prepare();
       mp1.start();
       break;
   case R.id.Button02:
       if (mp1.isPlaying())
       {
           mp1.stop();
           mp1.release();
       }
       mp2.reset();
       mp2.prepare();
       mp2.start();
       break;
```

mp1.prepare() and mp2.prepare() give IOException error.

Comment: check out my edit for my question, try this series of function calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Please note: *This is not the best way to do this*, this is very sloppy, this is just an idea

```
public void PlayRingFile(View view) {       
  switch (view.getId()) {
   case R.id.Button01:
    if (mp2.isPlaying()) {
       mp2.stop();    // stops the object from playing
       mp2.release(); // always a good practice to release the resource when done
     }
    MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.aaa);
    mp1.start();
    break;
   case R.id.Button02:
    if (mp1.isPlaying()) {
       mp1.stop();    // stops the object from playing
       mp1.release(); // always a good practice to release the resource
     }
    MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.bbb);
    mp2.start();
    break;        
 }
}
```

As I said, this isn't the best solution especially if you add more buttons then you would have to check every instance of `MediaPlayer` and there must be better ways of doing this.

My suggestions are to try to find a way to loop through all `MediaPlayer`'s to see if they are open and if so, release the resource and stop playing or maybe a way to stop all `MediaPlayer`'s from playing in general?

I will continue to look for other ways in the meantime, hope this points you in the right direction.

#### EDIT (12/30/09):

```
case R.id.Button01:
   if (mp2.isPlaying())  {
       mp2.stop();
       mp2.release();
   }
   mp1.reset();
   createMPlayer1(); // used to re-initialze the mediaplayer for reuse since resources were released.
   mp1.prepare();
   mp1.start();
   break;
case R.id.Button02:
   if (mp1.isPlaying()) {
       mp1.stop();
       mp1.release();
   }
   mp2.reset();
   createMPlayer2();
   mp2.prepare();
   mp2.start();
   break;

public void createMPlayer1() {
   MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.aaa);
}

public void createMPlayer2() {
   MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.bbb);
}
```

I think the IOException could be called when trying to access the file again after we have renoved the resouce. I added two methods to create the separate raw files since I believe the exception occurs when the resources are released. You can either re-initialized the `MediaPlayer`'s or try to discard releasing the resource.

Comment: I have not tried it yet, but I guess isPlaying is the key. And you're right about implementing a loop. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: No problem, I hope it all goes well.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked fine. But once mp2 is stopped it is not replaying. I modified the code so that I added mp.reset() and mp.prepare(), but this time mp1.prepare() and mp2.prepare() gave Unhandled exception type IOException error. Do you have any idea? Thank you for your time.

Comment: can you post your code as an edit in your question, so I can browse as whats happening?

Comment: Hi there. I added the new code to the question. It is the prepare function that gives the error in both mediaplayers. Thanks again.

Comment: This time setDataSource method is giving an error saying that: "The method setDataSource(Context, Uri) in the type MediaPlayer is not acceptable for the arguments (Context, int)"

Comment: I posted my edit too fast, I didn't get a chance to read the actual description of `setDataSource` where its used for playing a file or a stream, whereas your files as a raw resource. I am wondering you might have to create a function to (re)intialize the MediaPlayer's and then prepare them the same way you would normally and then play. If you need me to explain further I can jot down some code when I get home

Comment: I am new to Java. I will definitely appreciate if you could write a sample code.

Comment: out of curiosity, how did everything make out?

Comment: I decided to go with the issue, so when 2nd button is clicked the sound from the 1st button still plays. But, I have learned so much from our conversation. Thanks again.