# Android SDK - how to stop all mediaplayer at once

Tags: android, media-player

I made a soundboard, and the code creates a mediaplayer for every item when clicked.
Here's my code:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id){

Sound s = (Sound) mSounds.get(position);

MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, s.getSoundResourceId());

mp.start();

}
```

But I want to create a button to stop all sounds that are playing. Is there any way to stop ALL mediaplayer objects ?

Comment: You should maybe take a look at this question: [Is there a way to stop all MediaPlayers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1969975/562935)

Comment: This do not answer my question, actually I read that before posting. That tip works when the name of the Mediaplayer is fixed, and even if I did ONE MEDIA PLAYER FOR EACH SOUND, there is more than 120 sounds ... starting and stopping each one is not practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not put all MediaPlayers in a [Collection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collection.html)?

Then you can just iterate over the collection and stop them.

Comment: Can you give me an example ? I'm newbie.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Vector where adding all MediaPlayer instances and when you click on stop button you have to loop it stopping al instances with mp.stop();

Comment: The app contains more than 120 sounds, and when user click 2 times in one sound, 2 media players are created and no one is destroyed. So, with a loop, I would have to verify if is playing and then stop, one by one. This can consume a lot of CPU.

Comment: Iterating a vector of 1xx elements is not a problem. In each iteration you only have to do and if clause.If it is playing stop else remove of the vector... I don't know if there is other posibility of destroy all.